# Moveble label on timer

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I use Xamarin.Forms and I want create movable label on my application on realtime (on timer). I create this logic:

XAML code:

```
<ScrollView Grid.Row="0" VerticalOptions="End" 
                         Orientation="Horizontal" 
                         HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
                         Margin="0, 0, 0, 40"
                        x:Name="TickerTitleSound"
                        IsEnabled="False" 
                        >
                <Label
                Text="{Binding SpecialText}" />
            </ScrollView>
```

And C# code behind:

```
// Direction - bool class member
TickerTitleSound.Scrolled += (sender, e) =>
{
    double scrollingSpace = TickerTitleSound.ContentSize.Width - TickerTitleSound.Width;
    if(TickerTitleSound.ScrollX >= scrollingSpace)
    {
        Direction = false;
    }
    else if(TickerTitleSound.ScrollX <= 0)
    {
        Direction = true;
    }
};
Timer timerSound = new Timer() { Interval = 100 };
timerSound.Elapsed += async (o, e) =>
{
     await Task.Run(() =>
     {
         Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
         {
             if (Direction)
             {
                 TickerTitleSound.ScrollToAsync(TickerTitleSound.ScaleX + 10, 0, false);
             }
             else
             {
                 TickerTitleSound.ScrollToAsync(TickerTitleSound.ScaleX - 10, 0, false);
             }
          });
      });
};
timerSound.Start();
```

But this code not working. I want get this result:

[image]

How this make? I have

Comment: why are you using `ScaleX` instead of `ScrollX`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the TranslationX of label, here is my sample code below:

```
public partial class TestPage1 : ContentPage
{
    private bool Execute { get; set; }
    public TestPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        Label1.Text = "This is to simulate a really long sentence for testing purposes";
        Label1.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start;
        Label1.VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
        Label1.LineBreakMode = LineBreakMode.NoWrap;
    }
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        Execute = true;

        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50), () =>
        {
            Label1.TranslationX -= 5f;

            if (Math.Abs(Label1.TranslationX) > Width)
            {
                Label1.TranslationX = Label1.Width;
            }

            return Execute;
        });
    }
    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        base.OnDisappearing();

        Execute = false;
    }
}
```